# Series with matrices - cannot resolve error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have looked on various websites, and the TradingView documentation, and other coding site FAQs and educational info, and even AI for an answer to this problem, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to create a matrix variable as a series variable with the code below. If I uncomment the two lines with the comments "// OFFENDING LINE", it will still compile, but fail at run time with the error "Error on bar 4: Historical values of the array cannot be changed". Notice this bar 4 is one more than the maximum limit of my for loop. It always behaves that way. For example, if I make my for loop go to 5000 for its upper limit, the error will be reported for bar 5001.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code?

==================================================================================================

// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ZZZZZ

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Testing Matrices", overlay=true)

series matrix<float> mtxPatternSeries = na
mtxPatternSeries := matrix.new<float>(2,3,na)

(mtxPatternSeries[0]).set(0, 0, 7.555)

//if (bar_index > 3)                               // OFFENDING LINES - if uncommented, it still compiles, but fails at run time
//    (mtxPatternSeries[1]).set(0, 0, -55.5)       // OFFENDING LINES - if uncommented, it still compiles, but fails at run time

if (barstate.islast == true)
    for iCurBar=0 to 3
        log.info("\n(mtxPatternSeries[" + str.tostring(iCurBar) + "]).get(0, 0): " + str.tostring((mtxPatternSeries[iCurBar]).get(0, 0)) + "\n")
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=1.02*high, text="Last Bar:\n" + str.tostring(bar_index))
```

I tried running this code with and without the offending lines commented. I am trying to access the values inside matrices of past bars from the current bar.